# Image Replacement in JQuery Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually I am going to replace the images one after the other by jquery.I have the following code in jquery but it always place the last image in the image source.

```
for(var i = 0;i<2;++i)
{
  $("#heatMapImage").attr("src","");
  $("#heatMapImage").fadeOut(1000, function() {
  $("#heatMapImage").attr("src",i + ".png");
  }).fadeIn(9000);

  if(i == 2)
    $("#heatMapImage").attr("src",i + ".png");
}
```

And my html code is in the following.

```
<img id = "heatMapImage" src=""/>
```

And when the script runs it directly gives me the last image.And the html in inspect element looks like this,

```
<img id= "heatMapImage" src="2.png"/>
```

Please Help.

Comment: You have `i<2`, so `i` is never going to be 2. The highest it can be in the loop is 1.

Comment: You have an issue with closure in your code.

Comment: @BrianRay you're not thinking async enough.  `i` _will_ reach 2, since otherwise the loop doesn't terminate.  Unfortunately it does that _before_ the `.fadeOut` completion function gets called.

Comment: @Alnitak thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is more relating to the asynchronous nature of javascript.  You're running the fadeOut and fadeIn functions inside a loop, but the loop doesn't know to wait for the animations to finish before it increments.

Instead of using a for loop, you should move your fadeOut fadeIn code into a function and call the function recursively as your callback from the fadeIn.

```
var i = 0;

function fadeImages(i){
  $("#heatMapImage").attr("src","");
  $("#heatMapImage").fadeOut(1000, function() {
  $("#heatMapImage").attr("src",i + ".png");
  }).fadeIn(9000, function() {          
      if (i < 2) fadeImages(i + 1);
  });
}
```

Comment: right approach, but you've got `i` declared as a parameter _and_ in the outer score

Comment: Good call.  I forgot to pass `i` into the function.  Also, I incremented `i` before calling the function so I would have missed the first image.

Comment: it won't work like this, though - you're not passing the incremented `i` recursively

Comment: Remove the `i++` and just pass `i + 1` in the recursive call.

Comment: and now you no longer need the outer scoped `i` - but you should demo calling with `fadeImages(0)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94727/discussion-between-thingevery-and-alnitak).

Answer (score 0):

You use a callback inside a loop and passes a variable to it which is updated inside the loop. So when the callbacks are calling it , the updated variable will use the last state for all callbacks! see this thread for more info: When using callbacks inside a loop in javascript, is there any way to save a variable that's updated in the loop for use in the callback?